# React native iOS application crash in production mode

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, crash-reports

My application developed in react native and last version deployed on app store crashing with below given crash logs.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a66a927c __exceptionPreprocess + 228 (NSException.m:172)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a58839f8 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:557)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a65b34b0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116 (NSException.m:145)
3   Passport                        0x100cf4788 RCTFatal + 400
4   Passport                        0x100cf24a4 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 491
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1a66b0900 __invoking___ + 144
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1a65924d0 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 292 (NSForwarding.m:3052)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1a6593104 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 60 (NSForwarding.m:3123)
8   Passport                        0x100d056c8 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 491
9   Passport                        0x100d4514c facebook::react::invokeInner+ 495948 (RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 247
10  Passport                        0x100d44eac invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke+ 495276 (unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 87
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a60e8a38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1372)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a60e97d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:511)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a6092320 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592 (inline_internal.h:2441)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a6092e3c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428 (queue.c:3805)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a609b4a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596 (queue.c:5889)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a62c9114 _pthread_wqthread + 304 (pthread.c:2371)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1a62cbcd4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Same code working fine in development mode in application. I am not able to derive any meaningful information from crash report. Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code of file where it is crashed? I had the same issue 3days back and it was about empty destructuring.

Comment: Ravi, how you identified that spot in code ? As crash report not showing any sign of developer code. Crash only happens in live app. Same code working fine in debug mode.

Comment: In my case it was showing in logcat of iOS : `TypeError: TypeError: babelHelpers.objectDestructuringEmpty is not a function`

Comment: In my case it is not crashing while I run application in debug mode but live app crashes on iOS devices.

Comment: It was same for me also, try to run releas build from xcode with attached device, you might get some luck.

Comment: Yes, let me try with same. Thanks

Comment: If the app was originally built in Xcode < 10 and you recently upgraded to Xcode 10, check your build system settings (File -> Project Settings) and try changing it back to "Legacy Build System"